# Archive file generated by Xcode missing dylibs

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cmake

I’m developing an iOS app by using CMake to generate an Xcode project which gives me an application target and a couple of C++ dynamic libraries.

The problem is that when I archive it through Xcode the app in the archive file doesn't have any of the dylib files or other resources there which I have in the regular build tree. What am I missing in CMake? For my regular build I use CMake install for getting the dylibs in the application folder. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think that bare dylib-s are supported on iOS. Either compile them as static libraries (.a), or try to wrap as Frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

As battlmonstr mentioned, raw dylibs are not supported on iOS so I re-made them to frameworks. I also had to set the *Installation Directory* of the Framework (*Framework > Build Settings > Deployment*) to the correct path. For example, my archived file ends up in */User//Library/Developer/Xcode/Archive/*. In the archived file I have a *Product > Applications* folder which is where my archived application is stored. So in my *Installation Directory* path I would set the path to: */Applications/.app/Frameworks* to have my frameworks put there when I archive. Through CMake I set the following property for my framework:

```
XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_INSTALL_PATH "/Applications/${PROJECT_NAME}.app/Frameworks"
```

However, this changed propety *Dynamic Library Install Name Base* build setting for the Framework (*Framework > Build Settings > Dynamic Library Install Name Base*). This caused problems finding my frameworks through *rpaths* so I also had to set this property in CMake with the following:

```
XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE "@rpath"
```

As for resources, I found out that the easiest way to have them deployed to the right location in the archived file was by using the `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION` in CMake:

```
set_property(SOURCE ${MY_RESOURCES} PROPERTY MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION ${MY_RESOURCES_DEST_DIR})
```